# Node.js Passport GoogleStrategy how to access session data

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I use [Passport-Google-OAuth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth) to implement registration/login on my demo site. It works very well. Last several days I try to find solution how to access session variables inside "GoogleStrategy" implementation.

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuthStrategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    consumerKey: GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/google/callback"
},
function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    // Is it possible to access to session variables here, eg.:
    // var tmp = req.session.tmp;
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
    });
}));
```

I don't know is this possible. I need to update existing user in database, not to create new one, but can't "get" _id of existing user in this function.

Comment: Is findOrCreate not returning the correct user? It's a little unclear what you're asking.

Comment: findOrCreate is just example here, it works correctly... I need to get variable from session before call findOrCreate method.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs: http://passportjs.org/guide/authorize/

**Association in Verify Callback**

Set the strategy's passReqToCallback option to true. With this option enabled, req will be passed as the first argument to the verify callback.

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/twitter/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    if (!req.user) {
      // Not logged-in. Authenticate based on Twitter account.
    } else {
      // Logged in. Associate Twitter account with user.  Preserve the login
      // state by supplying the existing user after association.
      // return done(null, req.user);
    }
  }
));
```

With req passed as an argument, the verify callback can use the state of the request to tailor the authentication process, handling both authentication and authorization using a single strategy instance and set of routes. For example, if a user is already logged in, the newly "connected" account can be associated. Any additional application-specific properties set on req, including req.session, can be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding passReqToCallback: true and it should pass the req object into your callback, then add the req object as the first parameter in the callback
e.g.
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        passReqToCallback: true,
        consumerKey: …
}, function(req, token...